# Why the increment operator is not incrementing the value while assigning

Tags: c, increment, post-increment

why the Increment operator is working weird?

If
`int b = 2;`

and `b = b++ + b++ + b++;` //output is 9

Then why `b = b++ + b++;` //output is 5

**and not 6???**

Comment: This is undefined behaviour.  Any result is possible.  You may not both assign and increment the same variable.

Comment: `b++` returns the old value, and then increments the variable. `++b` increments the value, then returns the new value. When you do `b++ + b++`, you'll typically see the first `b++` evalulate to `2` (and increment `b` to `3`), and the second evaluate to `3` (and increment `b` to `4`). However, this is still undefined behavior, and won't always be the case.